# Evaluating an integral arising from reparametrization

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Could someone get me started on evaluating the following integral? I have no idea where to begin.

**Integral:** $$\int_0^t\frac{1}{k-\dfrac{Bs+m_0}{As+w_0}}ds$$

Thank you.

To zoom in just hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you have
$$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{k-\frac{Bs+m_0}{As+w_0}}ds
\\ =\int_{0}^{t} \frac{As+w_0}{k(As+w_0)-Bs-m_0}ds
\\=\int_{0}^{t} \frac{As+w_0}{(kA-B)s+w_0-m_0}ds
\\=\frac{A}{kA-B}\int_{0}^{t} \frac{(kA-B)s+(kA-B)\frac{w_0}{A}}{(kA-B)s+w_0-m_0}ds
\\=\frac{A}{kA-B}\int_{0}^{t} \frac{(kA-B)s+w_0-m_0-w_0+m_0(kA-B)\frac{w_0}{A}}{(kA-B)s+w_0-m_0}ds
\\=\frac{A}{kA-B}\int_{0}^{t}1+ \frac{-w_0+m_0(kA-B)\frac{w_0}{A}}{(kA-B)s+w_0-m_0}ds$$
Now you can complete

Comment: Remarkable! Far from simple though. Thank you.